# Filtering Django admin changelist to show specific rows based on the logged-in user

Tags: python, django

I have a django model like this:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Count=models.SmallIntegerField() 
   PriceUnitCode=models.ForeignKey(PriceUnit)
   Price=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   Description=models.TextField()
   ActionDate=models.CharField(max_length=16)
   ActionUser=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

When a user logs in the admin site, I would want the user to see only the Tour instances he has created (Tour instances for which the ActionUser is equal to the ID of logged-in user).

How can I filter the changelist based on logged-in users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks buddy
I tryed your code but it had error!!so I changed it and now it work well:

```
class TourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def queryset(self, request):
      qs = super(TourAdmin, self).queryset(request)
      if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
      return qs.filter(ActionUserCode=request.user)
admin.site.register(Tour,TourAdmin)
```

I put code for others who may have such problem

Answer (score 1):

in admins.py

```
class MyRegisteredTourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = Tour.objects.filter(action_user=request.user)
        return qs
admin.site.register(Tour,MyRegisteredTourAdmin)
```